# Como acessar o servidor puma rails local dentro de um container docker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, docker

Vou tentar ser o mais claro possível.

**Para contextualizar:**
Eu tenho uma aplicação que tem testes escritos em Capybara e que se conecta de modo remoto a um container docker para executar os testes.
Como eu uso o WSL, rodar o chrome local é algo que ainda não é possível, sendo assim, utilizo esse container do selenium.

**O problema:**
De dentro do meu container do selenium eu não consigo ter acesso a aplicação que está rodando localmente em minha máquina. Eu encontro muitas soluções quando se trata de um docker precisar de alguma forma acessar outro, porém não é o caso, tão pouco é o caso de expor portas do docker, porque a conexão que preciso é de dentro pra fora e não o inverso.
Ex: Quero poder digitar http://192.168.1.5:3000 (ip da minha máquina local) de dentro do container e que ele encontre minha aplicação rails rodando em minha máquina local.

PS.: Eu rodo dentro de um WSL, então o ip da minha network no windows e do WSL são diferentes, porém se eu acesso dessa forma pelo windows no ip do WSL eu encontro a aplicação, porque de dentro do container isso não é uma verdade?

*Alguém pode me ajudar?*

**EDIT:** Eu deletei todos os conteiners, todas as images e todos os networks do docker e comecei de novo e até o momento está funcionando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para, de dentro de um container, acessar o host, há um endereço específico do docker, não sendo necessário usar o IP, uma vez que este pode variar.

Utilize o endereço `host.docker.internal` e a porta que deseja (do host).